# Name of this Italian pastry?

Tags: italian-cuisine, pastry

Yesterday I bought this pastry filled with pistachio cream at Ponte di Castelvecchio in Verona, Italy. While it was very delicious, I forgot its name. Can somebody help?

[image: Italian pistachio pastry]

Comment: Craves a taste of this!

Comment: Is there a cake under the cream? And was it served very cold, almost frozen?

Comment: No, the cream was "uniform". And no, it was not served cold.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think these have a specific name, but it's possible to take a guess what they are made of.

The container is a "cialda", a thin waffle. [Here is a recipe with pictures](http://blog.giallozafferano.it/lebontadilisa/cialde-per-il-gelato/), basically it's done with a waffle iron with shallow ridges.

The cup is also lined with dark chocolate - the rough appearance suggests this was made in the shop and not bought already made.

What is inside is the hardest to guess, but I think it's likely some pistachio-flavoured "*crema pasticcera*", pastry cream. Likely milk (possibly also cream), sugar, pistachio paste, egg yolks, rice and corn starch.

The topping is made of crushed nuts, I'd say pistachios but the picture is too small to be sure.

Comment: Plus 1. I mention that based on the shape and size one can refer to them as "tartelletta", tough mainly tartellette are mini cakes and not waffle like.

Answer (score 0):

Those are pastries for when you're not able to make real pastries.

They're made with industrial pre-made ingredients. They taste good, but you can find better things.

Source: I'm italian.

Comment: but is there a name for it?  (and it makes sense ... the chocolate on the waffle to keep the wet ingredient from soaking it is often done for ice cream items that get held for some time)

Comment: No name, a generic "pasta" or "pasticcino" (pastry) is often used.